# Managing two tableviews in a single class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

**How to access two or more tableViews in a single class with tabledatasource and tabledelegates?**

Comment: you can set table view's tag to differentiate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a same delegate method you have to handle all tableviews,

For ex:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView==tableView1)
  //value for first tableview
else if(tableview==tableView2)
  //value for second tableview
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding them from XIB then answer from KingofBliss is right one, otherwise if you are adding them programmatically you can set tag property on them and then in delegate use it to distinguish which table are you working on.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if([tableView tag] == 1)
{
  //value for first tableview
} else {
  //value for second tableview
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableView tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] init];
when you create tableview give tag to them..

```
tableView1.tag         = 10;
tableView1.delegate    = self;
tableView1.dataSource  = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView1];
[tableView1 release]; 

UITableView tableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] init];
tableView2.tag         = 20;
tableView2.delegate    = self;
tableView2.dataSource  = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView2];
[tableView2 release];
```

And in delegate

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if(tableView.tag == tableView1.tag)
   //value for first tableview
 else if(tableview.tag==tableView2.tag)
   //value for second tableview
}
```

Comment: Thank you . Can we keep both the tableviews active at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is necessary to add two UITableViews and differentiate them, because same delegate functions are going to be called. Just add one UITabaleView and perform check on your data, set flags, for example if currently your UITableView is filled with Array1 and now you want to to fill it with Array2 just set flag and call **[UITableView reloadData]**.

Your problem solved.

As for as i suggest, adding two UITableViews in same class is not good practice